# Is there a way to install obs with python on windows?

Tags: python, obs

I've made an application that uses the obs virtual camera and I want to distribute it to my friends. The problem is that my friends are lazy and aren't bothering to install obs manually. I was hoping that I could install obs through the program itself so everything would be set up for them automatically. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fully automated install, you can use this script:

```py
import os
import zipfile

os.system("curl https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam/releases/download/2.0.4/OBS-VirtualCam2.0.4.zip -L -o OBS-VirtualCam2.0.4.zip")

with zipfile.ZipFile("OBS-VirtualCam2.0.4.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("C:/Program Files/")
os.system('regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\OBS-VirtualCam\bin\32bit\obs-virtualsource.dll"')
os.system('regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\OBS-VirtualCam\bin\64bit\obs-virtualsource.dll"')
```

full install using cmd tutorial can be found in [obs-studio github](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam) page

This script does this using python.

Comment: Thanks. I am running into an issue. This is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test3.py", line 6, in <module>
    with zipfile.ZipFile("OBS-VirtualCam2.0.4.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
  File "D:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "D:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: The problem is that the file isn't downloading correctly. I can tell because winrar isn't recognizing it as a zip either.

Comment: Try this using cmd `curl https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam/releases/download/2.0.4/OBS-VirtualCam2.0.4.zip -o OBS-VirtualCam2.0.4.zip`
if the problem exists, maybe _curl_ has issues.

Comment: Or instead of -o flag, use -L -o flags.

Comment: You're welcome, I've changed some other parts, use the new code. Hope this time don't give you any error.

Comment: I've used the new code. I'm getting a permission error this time.

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\OBS-VirtualCam'

Comment: Try `Run As Administrator` . Open cmd using Administrator and run your code.
`python your_python_file_name.py`

Comment: If this didn't solve the problem, you will have to take `Program Files` folder ownership, that isn't a good and safe way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. The best way would be to use the `os` library.

Code:

```py
import os
#importing os so we can use os.system
os.system("curl https://cdn-fastly.obsproject.com/downloads/OBS-Studio-27.0.1-Full-Installer-x64.exe -o installer.exe")
#os.system runs a command
os.system("installer.exe")
```

They would have to go through the install process, but that's basically just pressing next.